# Indo para um determinado tab

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Esse é meu menu:

```
<p:menubar>  
      <p:submenu label="Clientes">  
           <p:menuitem value="Cadastro" action="#{nomeBean.cadastrar} outcome="funcionario.xhtml" />  
           <p:menuitem value="Consulta" action="#{nomeBean.consultar}" outcome="funcionario.xhtml" />  
     </p:submenu>  
</p:menubar>
...    
<p:tabView dynamic="true" activeIndex="#{nomeBean.tabIndex}" >  
   <p:tab title="Cadastro">      
   </p:tab>  
   <p:tab title="Consulta">
      tenho aqui uma dataTable
   </p:tab>  
</p:tabView>
```

Esse é o meu Bean:

```
private int tabIndex;

public void cadastrar() {
  tabIndex = 0;
}

public void consultar() {
  tabIndex = 1;
}

public int getTabIndex() {
  return tabIndex;
}
```

Então, ao clicar no Menu consulta, por exemplo, ele não redireciona para o tab de consulta ou cadastro.

Answer (score 1):

Para funcionar precisarias atualizar o `p:tabView`, para tal:

1 - Defina um `id` par ao `p:tabView`(Exemplo: tabTeste);

2 - Para os items do menu, podes atualizar o p:tabView depois de ele terminar a solicitação assincrona ao servidor (neste caso a mudança do índice):

```
<p:menuitem value="Cadastro" update="tabTeste" action="#{nomeBean.cadastrar} outcome="funcionario.xhtml" />
```

**Recomendação:**

Podias fazer isso a nível de JavaScript, para evitar um "interação" com o servidor so para mudar índices bem definidos.

Comment: Eu não sei o que acontece, mas isso deveria funcionar...:/
Parece que o action não funciona, não seta o tabIndex.

Comment: Tente imprimir um texto nalgum dos métodos(cadastrar ou consultar) pra ver se ele exibe. Nota: Se tiveres um errozinho em JavaScript ele já nem passa pra fase seguinte do JSF. Tente abrir a console javascript do browser e ver que se passa.

Comment: Hy Cold, Obrigado pela ajuda..
Ele já está entrando no método e setando os valores.
Porém como o scopo é do tipo View ao redirecionar ele perde todos os dados.

Comment: Então muda o escopo dele, pois desse jeito está tudo a funcionar direito (sendo @ViewScoped)

Comment: É mudei para session consumiu muita memoria pois tenho uma tabela também..rsrs
E acabei achando um tal de FlahsScoped que salva o Objeto ou valor que voce quer na memoria.
Dentro do método vc faz a alteração.

public String redirecionarComFlash() {

FacesContext instance = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

ExternalContext externalContext = instance.getExternalContext();
externalContext.getFlash().put("key", valor);
externalContext.getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
return URL + "?faces-redirect=true";
}

Comment: Se isso der certo vou postar aqui..Mais uma vez Obrigado por disponibilizar a lógica!